# Software to notify me when someone rings my doorbell?

Tags: security, notification

I'm trying to get a notification on my main phone or email when someone rings my doorbell, without changing the doorbell. The sound is loud, so I'm thinking to set a secondary phone next to the intercom speaker, that would notify me once the dB level is higher than a certain threshold. Do you guys have any idea of how I could do this? Cheers!

Comment: can you code? or are you wiling to learn (maybe just copy some one else's code & modify it)?

Comment: Sure! My brother can code so I can get help from him :) @Mawg

Answer (score 1):

Since you & your brother are able to code, I will offer a software ***and hardware solution***, which could be fun hobby project.

I plan to do this some time soon, with a difference to you (but you might change your mind & do my project ;-)

### My Project

I am going to use an ESP32 (kinda like a smaller raspberry Pi, without Linux). They are well supported, with over 100 million sold, cheap, programmable and have both BlueTooth and WIfi.

I really like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32968683765.html), because LilyGo is a good brand. It costs about $17, which is a snip for something programmable and internet enabled.

[image]

It has a camera ***and*** an LCD display screen, which means that I can use it for two way communication. Wifi on the board is simple to program, to alert me when the door rings.

There are good [code samples](https://github.com/LilyGO/ESP32-Camera) to be had, so that you don't need to re-invent too much of the wheel. In fact, if you search for `esp32 face recognition`, you can even have that if you want.

### [image]

***BUT***, since you say

> I'm trying to get a notification on my main phone or email when someone rings my doorbell, without changing the doorbell.

Then all you need is a much cheaper ESP32 with no camera or LCD display, just a microphone (they are all internet enabled), which should costs about $5.

You can code them in C or Python, as you prefer; there are plenty of examples and forums. If you are interested, you might want to know about our [Internet Of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

And, once you can code an ESP32 with a microphone, you can make your own Alexa for five bucks. Just search for `esp32 voice recognition` (for instance, [this](https://www.hackster.io/news/the-arrival-of-esp32-based-voice-hardware-e3d9beab12c7)).

I may have missed the mark, or I may just have gotten you a new hobby. I know that I got bitten badly :-) Please let me know what you think ...

Answer (score 0):

An option that one might consider "off-the-shelf" would be [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com/), a web based service that uses internet connected devices (among other things) to provide responses to physical actions.

Your request could be as simple as a branch off your doorbell circuit that triggers one of the many network-capable devices to signal IFTTT to send a text message or email.

I did a [quick search](https://ifttt.com/search/query/doorbell) on the site for doorbell and got a bunch of results that may be of value, depending on your technical skill and budget. Even if one is not a perfect match, it may provide a path to a suitable solution.

Another option is called [Blynk](https://blynk.io/). It provides similar capability, based primarily on network-capable devices and one's cell phone. I was not able to find a search option in the site and did not sign up to investigate further, but the blog posts I receive from my Kickstarter contribution indicate that this service is also capable of solving your objective.